# Comparing TextField with new line

Tags: actionscript-3, compare, textfield, operator-keyword

```
import flash.text.TextField;
var txtBack:TextField=new TextField();

txtBack.text="\n";

trace(txtBack.text=="\n");
trace(txtBack.text=="");
```

Why does it trace false?

Comment: Try trimming `verticalText()` output and check. It's possible that TF does a `trim()` on its text to not store extensive whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I compare with `\r`.

It seems that AS3 converts any newlines automatically to the return carriage.

```
txtBack.text="\n";
trace(txtBack.text=="\r");

txtBack.text="\r";
trace(txtBack.text=="\r");
```

Traces `true` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've checked, and when you assign `text` property to a TextField, it calls an implicit `trim()`, or removes trailing newlines only. A simple test was like this:

```
            tf = new TextField();
        tf.text = 'a'; 
        addChild(tf); // to make traces valid
        trace(tf.textHeight); // traces 15
        tf.text = 'a\na'; 
        trace(tf.textHeight); // traces 30 - yes, 2 lines
        tf.text = 'a\n'; 
        trace(tf.textHeight); // traces 15!
```

Now, your `verticalText()` function returned a string that terminates with a newline character, which gets trimmed when you set `tf.text`, thus it stops being equal to `verticalText()` result.